# PC Board/Power Transistor heat dissipation

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb

I am attempting a repair on a failed Sansui 881 Receiver / There's an  obvious problem on the power supply board where the heat sink of a power transistor has 'legs' that are soldered to the PC Board, not connected in the circuit and have reached a temperature that has caused the board to discolor and  the circuit trace underneath to substantially lift off the board.  This is likely not to be the "fix" of the failure, but rather an aspect of it and I'd like to change the heat sink anchoring scenario to the steel chassis.   What was the wisdom in soldering the heat sink to the PC Board in the first place".  thanks

Comment: It seems that the product designer didn't calculate the power dissipation or proper failure protection was not there. But if this device was engineered correctly this won't happen.

Comment: Yes,  thank you. The design was likely due to the fact that the chassis has a number of  major components, each having their own PC board.  Fastening the heat sink to the chassis would have to have added a considerable amount of time on the assembly line.  Then of course, the system played quite well until a month or so ago, and then the 'dominoes" started toppling.   So the heat issue may have been insignificant before that.